# Linux command 'getent group' not returning users for some groups?

Tags: linux

I am using `getent group` command to get the `groups` along with there usernames in `linux`. But it is not showing any `usernames` for some `groups` which i know exist.

i need this info is there any other way around?

Picking up 1st two results :--

```
root:x:0: 
bin:x:1:bin,daemon
```

as you can see there are no users for group root and 2 users in bin group. I know that the root group contains a user root but its now showing it here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What is the return value of `getent` ? How does `/etc/nsswitch.conf` look like? (can you post it? )

Comment: picking up 1st 2 results:-                                    root:x:0:
bin:x:1:bin,daemon

Comment: @hek2mgl please refer to the updated question

Comment: just diff this to `cat /etc/group` and you'll see no difference. `getenet group` will likely output the same

Comment: @hek2mgl ya so any idea y its not showing the root user under the root group?

Comment: `getent` doesn't return users.

Comment: @hek2mgl but here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/ it clearly says it returns the list of users

Comment: @hek2mgl is there any other way around?

Comment: I see your problem, but I'll have to investigate this too. maybe some wise guy will teach us...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are missing is that each user has a primary group, which is stored in `/etc/passwd` (usually in field 4), and may have one or more supplementary groups. Only the supplementary group associations are in `/etc/group`, and as a result, are the only ones that `getent group` will show. In order to get the entire list of groups for a particular user, you can use `id -a <user>`, but you'll have to iterate that over the list of users to get your full information dump...

Comment: +1 - definitely the primary source of confusion. Beware of multiple entries (particularly in NIS+ or similar network group databases) where the same group number appears with different names in different entries. You can sometimes also find the same group name with different group numbers. I worked on a system with both sets of problems. Part of the trouble was a 1024-character limit on the length of a group entry, but groups needing more users than would fit in 1024 characters (that's why the duplicate numbers with different names). The same group name with different numbers was a config bug.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please run:

```
getent group|diff /etc/group -
```

and show us the difference in its output,

Since I have run this and I see no difference their both exactly the same

getent will only return the master group name and not the sub groups a user belongs to:

```
getent group adm
adm:x:4:me,logcheck
```

To get any instances of adm within getent try:

```
getent group|grep adm
```